# What happens when object is removed but there are still variables that point to it?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var a = {
  div: document.getElementById('#div')
};
```

What happens if the div gets removed?

Will the a.div object still be in memory?

Comment: It will point to undefined.

Comment: @MinusFour no it wont

Comment: I'm sorry, I might have misread the question. If you do: `delete a.div;` it will point to undefined. However... if you remove the DOM node from the document, then the object is still there and won't be collected by the GC... I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing a DOM element from the DOM does not do anything to other references that point to it.  So, if you do this:

```
var a = {
  div: document.getElementById('div')
};


var t = document.getElementById("div");
t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
t = null;
```

Then, `a.div` will still point to the original DOM object.  It will no longer be inserted in the DOM, but will still exist via the `a.div` reference.

The DOM element will still exist and any other references will still be alive and correct.  A removed DOM element is no longer in the DOM, but will not actually be deleted from memory until there are no more references to it - that's how garbage collection works.

---

P.S. You probably didn't mean to use `'#div'` with `document.getElementById()` as it takes just the id, with no selector prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how it's removed and what you're wanting to do. Take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ssj5pqj6/3/) fiddle. If you remove the element then you can't re-access it, it will just return null. But because you've already created a reference in memory that will exist unless you delete that variable. Notice that you can delete the element, then re-add it later on if you want.

```
<div id="target">Target</div>
<div id="toggle">Remove Element</div>
<div id="log">Log Element</div>
<div id="get">Get Element</div>
<div id="append">Re-append element</div>

<script>
var target = document.getElementById('target');

//log the variable
document.getElementById('log').addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(target);    
}, false);

//remove the element
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function(){
    target.parentElement.removeChild(target);
}, false);


//now check if the element exists
document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('target'));
}, false);


//re-add the previously deleted element
document.getElementById('append').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.body.appendChild(target);
}, false);
</script>
```